# What Is Your Complete ASP.net Development Environment?

Tags: asp.net

I assume that the basic setup for ASP.net web development today is:

1. Windows Vista (or XP)
2. Visual Studio 2008
3. SQL Server 2005
4. IIS 7
5. The .net Framework v3.5

So, what combination of tools, addons, libraries, etc do you always install to increase your productivity and support your development?

For me, it is always:

- [Ubuntu LAMP server](http://www.ubuntu.com/)
- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)
- [TRAC](http://trac.edgewall.org/)
- [The asp.net AJAX toolkit](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/)
- [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- [JQuery intellisense](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/02/06/vsdoc-for-jquery-1-3-1-now-available.aspx)
- [Free Text Box](http://freetextbox.com/)
- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
- [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)
- [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

I'd be very interested to know what your 'complete' development environment looks like today.

Edit - Added some more tools I forgot and made it a community wiki.  Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: Should be community wiki as it is a poll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic, plus

- [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)
- [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)
- [PowerCommands](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands)
- [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- Some various JQuery Plugins
- The [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/)
- AJAX Tool Kit
- MySQL I also have SQL Sever 2005
- [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)
- [Paint .NET](http://www.getpaint.net/)
- [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html)
- [Pixie](http://www.nattyware.com/pixie.php)
- [Star UML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/)
- [Snippet Designer](http://www.codeplex.com/SnippetDesigner)

Answer (score 2):

The basic plus:

- Resharper
- Subversion
- AJAX Tool Kit
- FCKEditor
- Reflector
- Re-Motion ([re-motion](http://www.re-motion.org/))
- Test-Driven .Net
- HTTPWatch
- DotNetTrace
- [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. Similar to above

Professionally:

- XP / Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6)
- VS2008 Standard
- SQL Server 2005
- NUnit
- jQuery
- TinyMCE
- Visual Source Safe (eeek!!)
- SQL Effects Clarity
- GhostDoc
- Fiddler
- [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) (best of the lot)

Personally:

- Vista / Ubuntu
- MySql 5
- VS2008 / MonoDevelop
- Subversion

And how could I forget, .NET reflector

Comment: +1 for beyond compare - and yes it's the best comparison tool

Answer (score 2):

- Windows Vista (Please let Win7 be as good as people are saying)
- IIS 7
- .Net 3.5
- VS 2008
- SourceGear
- CruiseControl (just got it setup and loving it)
- Resharper (CAN NOT live without)
- StyleCop (Just started using it, what a pain but it'll pay off in the end)
- FxCop ( See StyleCop comment)
- Firebug (Resisted at first...have no idea why)
- Telerik Ajax Suite (Pricey and bloated...but pretty to look at)
- Notepad++ (Quick and painless)
- Free SMTP Server (No SMTP server on Vista)
- Nunit (Like it...wish I was a guru and will use more and more)
- Reflector ("So...how did the smart guys do it...")
- CAT.NET (stay away evil doers)
- Ritalin ("Thank the maker")

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP
Visual Studio 2005 and 2008
SQL SErver 2005
IIS 6
.NET Framework 3.5

- ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit
- [ComponentArt    WebUI components](http://www.componentart.com)
- [BasicDatePicker](http://www.basicdatepicker.com)
- [ReSharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper)
- [SQL Toolbelt](http://www.red-gate.com) by RedGate Software

Answer (score 0):

Basic plus:

- [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)
- [CodeSmith Pro](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) (mainly for use with [NetTiers templates](http://nettiers.com/))
- Some [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/) tools (SQL Compare v.useful)
- .NET Reflector (also from RedGate now)
- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) / [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/)
- [Web Developer plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) for Firefox
- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/)

& WinAmp :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my basic setup:

- Windows XP Pro SP3
- IIS 5.1
- .Net 2.0,3.0, and 3.5
- VS 2008
- Subversion(new code), Viusal SourceSafe (legacy code)
- CruiseControl
- Resharper
- nAnt

Process overview points

- Agile
- Scrum
- XP
- TDD

Answer (score 0):

Added to your basics

- NUnit Framework
- Castle Windsor (Inversion of Control container)
- NHibernate ORM with Fluent NHibernate
- Resharper TestDriven.net NBehave (for BDD style unit testing)
- Subversion
- Tortoise SVN (windows integration for subversion)
- Visual SVN (for VS integration for subversion and subversion server management)
- Castle Validators
- Firebug
- Team City (for continuous integration)
- Rhino Mocks (for mocking and stubs)
- JQuery and various plugins
- Rake for automatic building on new projects and NANT on legacy projects
- Red gate SQL Compaire and SQL Data Compaire (essental for moving database around)
- Auto Mapper (converting domain models to Data transfer objects)
- Log4Net for logging

Comment: do you really use automapper along with NHibernate?
i like the concept of automapper, but i don't think i will be able to justify the performance hit for an asp.net web app.

Comment: @ronaldwidha yeah have never had a problem using both. There is that big a performance hit. only place you might get some is with the reflection which is negligible these days

Answer (score 0):

basic, plus:

- SuperPreview
- LinqPad for linq to sql
- DbDeploy (database versioning)

Answer (score 0):

Platform

- Windows Server 2008 x64
- IIS 7
- Web Platform Installer
- PHP
- .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 SP1
- IE8 (JS Console is great!) + Firefox (FireBug)
- SQL Server 2008

Dev

- Visual Studio 2008 SP1
- Resharper 4
- TFS and / or SourceGear Vault
- Notepad++
- .NET Reflector
- ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit
- jQuery (cannot live without it)

SharePoint

- MOSS 2007 (Enterprise) (SP2)
- SharePoint Designer 2007
- Stramit CAML Viewer
- U2U CAMLBuilder
- VSeWSS 1.3
- WSPBuilder
- Telerik RadEditor fior SharePoint
- jQuery (cannot live without it)